# regex: how to match a line according to the previous line

Tags: regex, ctags

I have a .pdb file (a molecular coordinates file) that contains many lines
that look like these.

I'm interested into writing ctags options to be able to generate tags for such file formats and fly over them with Vim.

```
SOMETHING      0.000000  0.021483  0.000000        0.00000                         
SOMETHING      0.000000  0.000000  0.008964        0.00000                         
ATOM      1 
ATOM      2 
ATOM      3 
ATOM      4 
ATOM      5 
SOMETHING      0.000000  0.021483  0.000000        0.00000                         
SOMETHING      0.000000  0.000000  0.008964        0.00000
ATOM      6 
ATOM      7 
...
```

so what I would do to create tags for ATOM entries is to edit .ctags into:

```
--langdef=PDB
--langmap=PDB:.pub
--regex-pdb=/^ATOM/a,atom/
```

of course, the result is that each atom gets its own tag.
What I'd really want is to match only the first occurrence (or each new occurrence) of the same keyword. i.e., to tag ATOM keywords:

```
ATOM      1
ATOM      6
```

I've tried with negative lookbacks but I'm missing something...

EDIT:
testing regex on https://regexr.com using `(^[A-Z]+).*$\s(?!\1)` gives me an acceptable result, substantially matching every last occurrence of each same-keyword block.
Unfortunately Universal ctags, while supporting `--mline-regexp=` does not support lookback/lookaheads...

EDIT - SOLVED:

thank you to everyone who replied to my post, I eventually managed to achieve what I was looking for putting together some of your suggestions.
A nice working solution is:

```
--mline-regex-PDB=/(^ATOM).*$[[:space:]](ATOM.*$[[:space:]])*/\1/a/{mgroup=1}{_advanceTo=2end}
```

what it does is the following:

- `(^ATOM)` match ATOM word at beginning of the line
- `.*$` and the whole line itself, whatever it contains.
- `[[:space:]]` POSIX character class to match the line break
- `(ATOM.*$[[:space:]])*` this is basically: and every line afterwards that starts with `ATOM`
- `/\1/a/` tag name will be what matches group 1 (first ATOM match) and of kind `a`
- `{mgroup=1}` the tags will point to the line at which group 1 matches
- `{_advanceTo=2end}` reiterate the pattern search at the end of group 2 (i.e. a chunk of contiguous lines starting with ATOM, this is what does the magic ;)

Comment: Isn't space characters before ATOM?

Comment: I'm sorry, each line begins with an uppercase keyword, I might have formatted it badly here on my question

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: does ctags support conditional statements?

```
^(ATOM\s+\d+\s*$)?(?(1)|.*\n+^(ATOM\s+\d+)\s*$)
```

Check it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DZxuz0/1)

Try the next regex:

```
^(?!ATOM\s+\d+\s*).+$\n+^(ATOM\s+\d+)\s*$
```

Comment: thanks a lot! it works unfortunately my problem is upstream: ctags regex does not support (?!pattern) expressions...

Comment: Ctags doesn't allow neither cond. statements nor backreferences at least within the pattern matcher regex. But I eventually managed to get it to work, also thanks to @Masatake reply

Answer (score 0):

Universal-ctags(https://ctags.io) has experiemntal multiline regex meta parser.

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.pdb 
cat /tmp/foo.pdb 
SOMETHING      0.000000  0.021483  0.000000        0.00000                         
SOMETHING      0.000000  0.000000  0.008964        0.00000                         
ATOM      1 
ATOM      2 
ATOM      3 
ATOM      4 
ATOM      5 
SOMETHING      0.000000  0.021483  0.000000        0.00000                         
SOMETHING      0.000000  0.000000  0.008964        0.00000
ATOM      6 
ATOM      7
SOMETHING      0.000000  0.021483  0.000000        0.00000                         
SOMETHING      0.000000  0.000000  0.008964        0.00000
ATOM      8
SOMETHING      0.000000  0.000000  0.008964        0.00000
ATOM      9
$ cat pdb.ctags
cat pdb.ctags
--langdef=PDB
--langmap=PDB:.pdb
--kinddef-PDB=a,atom,atoms
--mline-regex-PDB=/^ATOM[[:space:]]+(([[:digit:]]*)([[:space:]]+ATOM[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]]*))*)/\2/a/{mgroup=2}{_advanceTo=1end}
$ ./ctags --fields=+K -o - --options=pdb.ctags /tmp/foo.pdb 
1   /tmp/foo.pdb    /^ATOM      1 $/;"  atom
6   /tmp/foo.pdb    /^ATOM      6 $/;"  atom
8   /tmp/foo.pdb    /^ATOM      8$/;"   atom
9   /tmp/foo.pdb    /^ATOM      9$/;"   atom
```

Comment: beautiful! I haven't thought about this, but eventually I did something similar:

Comment: ehm.. newbie here.. I meant... `--mline-regex-PDB=/^([^A]|A[^T]).*$[[:space:]](^ATOM)/\2/a,atom/{mgroup=2}{_advanceTo=2start}`